# How to give minimum required space to Column element and rest of the space to other element in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

Let's say I have 2 widgets (Widget_A & Widget_B) in a Column on my flutter app. Widget_A contains a SingleChildScrollView() and Widget_B contains a Column on some fixed height elements. I have tried to demonstrate the scenario with the image below.
[image: Diagram for the scenario]

Now the problem is I want Widget_B to take as minimum space as it requires and Widget_A to take all the available space. I tried to do this using Expanded() widget with a flex value. But if I give flex to Widget_B based on a bigger screen devices, it gives overflow to smaller screen devices like iPhone SE (as Widget_B contains fixed height elements). When I am trying to give flex to Widget_B based on a smaller screen devices, It leaves a large blank space below Widget_B.

I have also tried to wrap Widget_A with SizedBox.expand() and Widget_B with SizedBox.shrink(). But it throws some kind of exception. I am attaching a screenshot of the exception below.

[image: Exception occured while using SizedBox()]

Please guide me, what should I do in this scenario. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take maximum available space, a child widget in a `Column` or `Row` should be wrapped in [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html). `Expanded` also have [flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) parameter, so you can proportion several widgets to your liking.

Here's sample code of what you're asking.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  height: 1200,
                  child: Center(
                    child:  Text('Widget A SingleChildScrollView content'),
                  ),
                
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
        children: const [
           SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child:  Text('Widget B child 1'),
          ),
           SizedBox(
            height: 20,
            child:  Text('Widget B child 2'),
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Other than that you have to make sure that `SingleChildScrollView`'s child does not have unconstrained height.